# How to represent "Data.Map Text Text" in Dhall?

Tags: haskell, yaml, dhall

If I have a type in Haskell like this:

```
data MyType = MyType
  { env :: Map Text Text
  }
```

How can I represent a value of `MyType` in Dhall?

```
{ env = ???
}
```

What I want to do is to write values of `MyType` in Dhall and then read it in from Haskell and unmarshal it into `MyType`, like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- input auto "./config"
    print (x :: MyType)
```

I'm coming from `Data.Aeson` and YAML where you can represent maps like this:

```
env:
  KEY1: "foo"
  KEY2: "bar"
```

(you would be able to parse the above into the `MyType` type using Aeson's `decodeFileEither`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found three workarounds. Skip to the bottom if you want
the best workaround until
[`toMap`](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/issues/234#issuecomment-422478261) lands.

As of 2019-05-05 there is no way to represent maps in Dhall like how it is
possible with Aeson/YAML (although support for a native `toMap` function is
coming soon). So for now we basically have to use a list of homogeneous
records. It's a bit clunky, but at least you get the native unmarshaling.

If we want to use a list of tuples instead of a map, we can do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards     #-}

module Tuple where

import Dhall
import qualified Data.Text as T

data MyType = MyType { env :: [MyTuple] }
    deriving (Generic, Show)

instance Interpret MyType

newtype MyTuple = MyTuple (T.Text, T.Text)
    deriving (Interpret, Show)

-- input auto "{env = [{_1= \"HOME\", _2 = \"foo\"}] }" :: IO MyType
```

The above was adapted from [this
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54642516/437583), which showed a way to
parse IP addresses as 4-element tuples.

For parsing into a Map, we can do:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}

module MapA where

import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Dhall

import qualified Data.Map

data MyType = MyType { env :: Map Text Text }
    deriving (Generic, Show)

data KeyValue a = KeyValue { mapKey :: Text, mapValue :: a }
    deriving (Generic, Show)

toMap :: [KeyValue a] -> Map Text a
toMap keyValues = Data.Map.fromList (map adapt keyValues)
  where
    adapt (KeyValue {..}) = (mapKey, mapValue)

instance Interpret MyType
instance Interpret a => Interpret (KeyValue a)

-- Wrap `Map` in a newtype if you want to avoid an orphan instance
instance Interpret a => Interpret (Map Text a) where
    autoWith options = fmap toMap (autoWith options)

-- input auto "{env = [{mapKey = \"HOME\", mapValue = \"foo\"}] }" :: IO MapA.MyType
```

The above was adapted from this
[comment](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-haskell/issues/505#issuecomment-403248928). The idea is to make
records that look like `{ mapKey = X, mapValue = Y}` parseable, and then to
convert any lists of such records into a Map. Notice how we support any value
type, not just text (so we can have `env` in `MyType` be `Map Text Int` or
something else, if we wanted to). This solution has just 1 type variable `a`
for the values in the map, but I suppose it is possible to make the keys more
generic as well.

OK so after some tweaking, I got the following to compile, which supports both
keys and values to be generic as well:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}

module MapKV where

import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Dhall

import qualified Data.Map

data MyType = MyType { env :: Map Text Text }
    deriving (Generic, Show)

data MyTypeInts = MyTypeInts { envInts :: Map Integer Integer }
    deriving (Generic, Show)

data KeyValue k v = KeyValue { mapKey :: k, mapValue :: v }
    deriving (Generic, Show)

toMap :: Ord k => [KeyValue k v] -> Map k v
toMap keyValues = Data.Map.fromList (map adapt keyValues)
  where
    adapt (KeyValue {..}) = (mapKey, mapValue)

instance Interpret MyType
instance Interpret MyTypeInts
instance (Interpret k, Interpret v) => Interpret (KeyValue k v)

-- Wrap `Map` in a newtype if you want to avoid an orphan instance
instance (Ord k, Interpret k, Interpret v) => Interpret (Map k v) where
    autoWith options = fmap toMap (autoWith options)

-- input auto "{env = [{mapKey = +1, mapValue = \"foo\"}] }" :: IO MapKV.MyType
-- input auto "{envInts = [{mapKey = +1, mapValue = -22 }] }" :: IO MapKV.MyTypeInts
```

Lastly here is a version that avoids the orphan instance that uses an `Env` newtype wrapper:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}

module MapKV where

import Data.Map (Map)
import Dhall

import qualified Data.Map

data MyType = MyType { env :: Env }
    deriving (Generic, Show)

newtype Env = Env (Map Text Text)
  deriving (Eq, Generic, Show)

data KeyValue k v = KeyValue { mapKey :: k, mapValue :: v }
    deriving (Generic, Show)

toMap :: Ord k => [KeyValue k v] -> Map k v
toMap keyValues = Data.Map.fromList (map adapt keyValues)
  where
    adapt (KeyValue {..}) = (mapKey, mapValue)

instance Interpret MyType
instance (Interpret k, Interpret v) => Interpret (KeyValue k v)

instance Interpret Env where
    autoWith options = fmap (Env . toMap) (autoWith options)

-- input auto "{env = [{mapKey = \"HOME\", mapValue = \"foo\"}] }" :: IO MapKV.MyType
```